# Connecting to Mongo stateful set from another pod (Node js) in Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongoose, deployment

I'm new to kubernetes and learning to launch stateful set using mongo image.

I have a statefulset.yaml which creates a mongo stateful set and a headless service using ClusterIp. On the other pod, I have a Node js running and using mongoose to connect to the Mongodb cluster.

Error:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo-0.mongo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
```

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

Connection String:

```
mongodb://${username}:${password}@mongo-0.mongo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:27017/${database}?replicaSet=${replicaSetName},directConnection=true
```

Updated Yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-svc
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: mongo-svc
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-data
              mountPath: /data/db
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              value: "admin"
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: "password"
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
              value: "skippy"
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /bin/sh
                  - -c
                  - >
                    if [ ! -f /data/db/admin-user.lock ]; then
                      sleep 5;
                      touch /data/db/admin-user.lock
                      if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "mongo-0" ]; then
                        mongo --eval 'db = db.getSiblingDB("admin"); db.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "password", roles: [{ role: "root", db: "admin" }]});';
                      fi;
                      mongod --shutdown;
                    fi;
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mongo-data
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
```

Node js:

```
    const username = 'admin';
    const password = 'password';
    const database = 'skippy';

    // Use the StatefulSet service name to reach any MongoDB pod
    const clusterServiceName = 'mongo-s';

    // MongoDB StatefulSet replica set name
    const replicaSetName = 'rs0';

    // Create the connection string with all replica set members
    const uri = `mongodb://${username}:${password}@mongo-0.mongo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:27017/${database}?replicaSet=${replicaSetName},directConnection=true`;

    const connection = setInterval(() => {
        logger.debug(`Mongoose connection initiated ${uri}`);
        mongoose
            .connect(uri)
            .then((e: any) => {
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                logger.error(`MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. ${err}`);
            });
    }, 5000);

    mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
        logger.debug('MongoDB connection opened');
        clearInterval(connection);
    });
};
```

Comment: What problem are you running into; can you [edit] the question to include an actual question, and a specific error message if you have one?  One thing I see is that your Service requires both `name` and `role` tags, but the StatefulSet's Pod template only has `role`, which could cause a connection to fail.

Comment: I did try adding the name tag - thanks for that. But, unfortunately, nothing has changed wrt error. Still it's trying to connect and failing - 
**MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo-0.mongo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local**

Comment: The Service `selector:`/Pod `labels:` mismatch would cause this.